# No implementation found when i use .so file android

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, implementation, .so

i want to use native library from other project. here is my library.
[image: .so library]

it is my first time to use ndk in android studio. i succedd to load library .so, but failed when i want to access the file. here is the error
[image: error description]

here is my java code that load the library.
[image: jni]

here is my main java code 
[image: main]

can you solve my problem? thanks

Comment: If you want to reuse an existing native library, you should use the Java classes that come with it. In the worst case, you can try to reproduce these classes yourself, by reverse engineering the so file.

Comment: how to reverse engineering so file? any advice or tutorial link?

Comment: Let me answer your question with a question. You tried to call the method **GetLibVersion()**. Why do you think it should exist in **libsmart_connection_jni.so**?

Comment: i have an example project that include jni folder and libs. here is the link https://github.com/CassieLuoli/react-native-smartconnection . and i want to make it on android native / android studio. i've read that we just need .so file so we can get the library without make c file again. and GetLibVersion() exist in the jni folder.

Comment: Post code, not pictures of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [link](https://github.com/CassieLuoli/react-native-smartconnection) to the example project that you provided in comments, the life is really easy.

You need the file https://github.com/CassieLuoli/react-native-smartconnection/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/mediatek/demo/smartconnection/JniLoader.java `as is` in your project. Download it from GitHub without changing the class name or the package and use it in your Java app, like they do in their [example](https://github.com/CassieLuoli/react-native-smartconnection/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/luoli/smartconnection/SmartConfigHelper.java).

Comment: owh, it worked now :). and other question, if i want to change the logic of library, is it possible to change inside .so file? if you can, can you answer the question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55096800/how-to-use-other-jni-file-c-h-mk-from-other-project-in-android-studio ? i want to change the logic of .c file but i confused how to use those file and want to make it work first before i change the logic. it use same github file like before :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the JNI layer in your C part. To let Java native interface `GetLibVersion()` to be able to find a matching function in C part, you need to define a C function name with `Java_ai_widya_mediatekso_JniLoader_GetLibVersion(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz)` as the crash log told you. Don't miss the JNI parameters in the C function.
If you want to have the exact same function name in the C part as the Java part, you can register a new name to JVM. Call below function in your JNI_Onload().

```
static int registerNativeMethods(JNIEnv* env)
{
    jclass clazz;
    const char* className = "ai/widya/mediatekso/JniLoader";
    clazz = env->FindClass(className);
    if (clazz == NULL) {
        ALOGE("Native registration unable to find class '%s'", className);
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }
    JNINativeMethod methods[] = {
        {"GetLibVersion", "()V", (void*) GetLibVersion },
        {"GetProtoVersion", "()V", (void*) GetProtoVersion },
    };
    if (env->RegisterNatives(clazz, methods, 2) < 0) {
        ALOGE("RegisterNatives failed for '%s'", className);
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }
    return JNI_TRUE;
}
```

And don't forget to add the JNI parameters to in your C functions like this `GetLibVersion(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz)`.

Comment: so i have to make a c file?